# SQLX "missing destination name" when using table name in the struct tag

Tags: database, go, sqlx

The issue is that when I use struct tags with an object, they do not work properly. I've worked on projects before that have done the same thing but have had no issue, but I can't figure out why.

Example:

this does not work:

```
type Category struct {  
   ID          int            `json:"id" db:"category.id"`  
   Name        string         `json:"name" db:"category.name"`   
   Description string         `json:"description" db:"category.description"` 
}
```

error received:
`missing destination name id in *[]Category`

this works fine:

```
type Category struct {  
   ID          int            `json:"id" db:"id"`   
   Name        string         `json:"name" db:"name"`    
   Description string         `json:"description" db:"description"` 
}
```

query:

```
result := []Category{}
query := `
    SELECT category.id, category.name, category.description FROM category;
    `
err := sqlx.Select(db, &result, query)
```

Running the query in a SQL editor works just fine. I also have worked on a proprietary project where prepending the table name to the tag works fine but for whatever reason I can't seem to get it going with this.

Appreciate the help,

EDIT:

using mysql

Comment: What database are you using? Looks like on MySQL, it omits the table name from the selected columns, even if they are ambiguous.

Comment: I think SQLx expects the direct struct fields to have unqualified names. The "table.field" notation is parsed as embedded structs. I have a few structs that embed other structs and I use the "table.field" notation to scan both the outer and the embedded struct at the same time in a single query.

Comment: @MadWombat The thing is that I have done that (without nesting structs) in a different project and it has worked. Unfortunately, I can't link the thing because the code is not open source. It used mysql as well. I wonder if there's a mysql setting or sqlx setting I can change to get this working but a couple hours' Googling and experimenting did not get me anywhere so I thought I'd ask

Comment: @RayfenWindspear yeah you were right, the solution was to add `columnsWithAlias=true` into the connection -_- I feel like an idiot

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to answer your own question. I'm sure someone, somewhere, will find this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was actually made in the connection step!

I needed to add `columnsWithAlias=true` to the connection parameters and the code worked fine.

Thanks to RayfenWindspear for the tip that mysql doesn't send column names by default.